# Move 2 scroll bar at same time

Tags: java, scroll, javafx, scrollbar, javafx-8

In my `JavaFX` project I have a 2 `TextFlows` in a `splitpane` wrapped in 2 scroll panes. How can I scroll both scroll panes at same time.
Or simply bind scroll bar to other scroll bar?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would also solve your problem:

```
scrolPane1.vvalueProperty().bindBiderectional(scrolPane2.vvalueProperty());
```

That's it! :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by adding event listener to vvaluepropert of each scrollpane. I'm posting the answer here. SO if someone need hope this will help.

```
scrolPane1.vvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
             if((Double)newValue < scrolPane2.getVmax())
                   scrolPane2.setVvalue((Double)newValue);
      }
});

scrolPane2.vvalueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
      @Override
      public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
             if((Double)newValue < scrolPane1.getVmax())
                  scrolPane1.setVvalue((Double)newValue);
      }
});
```

Comment: hmm .. why don't you simply bide-bind the two values?